# How can I change the main display in a Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have 3 monitors on my main setup and often connect to a laptop from my work (both Windows 10 Pro).

On the Windows RDC (Remote Desktop Connection) launcher I have the option "use all my monitors" option checked.

What I would like to do is to change the main display in the RDC only. Let's say I have the main display setted as 1, on the main setup. I would like to keep the main monitor as 1 on the main setup and have the RDC main monitor as monitor 2.

Here is what I see when trying to change the main display on the RDC: https://imgur.com/a/1IQC3tD

Is this possible to achieve with RDC? I can use other software to aid this, but can't change the remote connection software. (I can only use this software for remote connections)

Comment: As far as I know RDC doesn't have any provisions for this. If you get an answer to this question I'll be a very happy customer too :-)

Comment: Thanks @Tonny. You can help by upvoting the question so it gets to more people!

Comment: I though I already did, but I must have accidentally clicked besides the arrow. It is upvoted now.